# laravel5 generate routes key

Tags: php, laravel-5

i use laravel 5.2 now.
i have these codes in my routes.php file:

```
Route::(['dashboard'=>'DashboardArticelController',]);
```

and laravel generates some router for my app :

GET  /dashboard/my-articles      App\Http\Controllers\DashboardArticelController@getMyArticles

here is a method in my controller:

```
public function getMyArticles()
{
    //$articels = Auth::user()->articals()->latest('published_at')->get(); 
    //dd(Auth::user()->articals()->latest('published_at')->simplePaginate(3));
    $articels = Auth::user()->articals()->latest('published_at')->Paginate(5);      
    return view('dashboard.view.dashboardArticelEdit',compact('articels'));
}
```

i wonder how the laravel5 generates this route ,i can not found the method can generates the route with the method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Laravel assumes an Eloquent model should map to URL segments using its id column. But what if you expect it to always map to a slug?

Eloquent implements the Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable contract, which means every Eloquent object has a getRouteKeyName() method on it that defines which column should be used to look it up from a URL. By default this is set to id, but you can override that on any Eloquent model:

```
class Test extends Model 
{
   public function getRouteKeyName()
   {
      return 'slug';
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks.but i found there is a method 'boot' in class RouteServiceProvider,when i add this statment:$router->model('one','App\Articles'); into that method.i will get the model object App\Articles to my method 'public function getMyArticles($Articles)'.but the method 'Route::(['dashboard'=>'DashboardArticelController',]);'generate some routes like: GET /dashboard/my-articles/{one?}/{tow?}/... how can i change the key {one?} to {articles?} .because i want to generate some other routes with Route::controllers([]).they both generate the routes with 'path/{one?}/{two?}/...'

Comment: you need to bind implicit route model refer this article https://mattstauffer.co/blog/implicit-model-binding-in-laravel-5-2 . You will get better idea.